# how do i use vars, functions and structs in other files?

Tags: c

In `timer.c` I have

```
typedef struct Timer {

    int startTicks;
    int pausedTicks;

    int paused;
    int started;

} Timer;

void Init( Timer *t )
{
    t->startTicks = 0;
    t->pausedTicks = 0;
    t->paused = 0;
    t->started = 0;
}
```

What do i need to do in main.c to make use of this struct and functions in that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, .c files contain definitions and .h files contain declarations. A better approach would be to keep your definitions in a header:

```
//timer.h
#ifndef TIMER_H //include guard
#define TIMER_H

typedef struct Timer { //struct declaration

    int startTicks;
    int pausedTicks;

    int paused;
    int started;

} Timer;

void Init( Timer *t ); //method declaration

#endif


//timer.c
#include "timer.h"

void Init( Timer *t ) //method definition
{
    t->startTicks = 0;
    t->pausedTicks = 0;
    t->paused = 0;
    t->started = 0;
}

//main.c
#include "timer.h"  //include declarations
int main()
{
    Timer* t = malloc(sizeof(Timer));
    Init(t);
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The C programming language for dummys books are sooo thin.

Comment: Don't use that book then... you'll learn more online. Or get yourself a proper book.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use [header files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file) (usually named `*.h`)  and `#include` them.

Learn how to compile a program with several compilation units, e.g. with a [Makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile).

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debugging information (with GCC, that means `gcc -g -Wall`, i.e. `CFLAGS=-g -Wall` in your `Makefile`).

Comment: +1 but this may be a single file (I mean, it's possible that header file is not necessary)

Comment: The original poster mention two files `timer.c` and `main.c`. So for a newbie, having a common header and using `make` is useful.